# ffmpeg coversion for rtmp stream, fname empty

Tags: nginx, ffmpeg, http-live-streaming, rtmp

I want to use HLS_Variant feature for the NGINX rtmp Module.
But if I follow the examples in the documentation I can't get it to work.

I have the following test:

```
application Test {
                live on;
                record off;

                on_publish http://127.0.0.1/php/rtmp_auth.php;
                on_publish_done http://127.0.0.1/php/on_publish_done.php;

                exec_push /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -loglevel debug -i rtmp://localhost:1935/Test/$name
               -c:v libx264 -acodec aac -preset veryfast -b:v 256k -tune zerolatency -vf "scale=480:trunc(ow/a/2)*2" -f flv  rtmp://localhost:1935/Z006/$name_low
               -c:v libx264 -acodec aac -preset veryfast -b:v 768k -tune zerolatency -vf "scale=720:trunc(ow/a/2)*2" -f flv  rtmp://localhost:1935/Z006/$name_mid
               -c:v libx264 -acodec aac -preset veryfast -b:v 1024k -tune zerolatency -vf "scale=960:trunc(ow/a/2)*2" -f flv  rtmp://localhost:1935/Z006/$name_high
               -c:v libx264 -acodec aac -preset veryfast -b:v 1920k -tune zerolatency -vf "scale=1280:trunc(ow/a/2)*2" -f flv  rtmp://localhost:1935/Z006/$name_higher
               -c copy -f flv rtmp://localhost:1935/Z006/$name_src 2>>/tmp/Log.log; }

        application Z006 {
                live on;
                record off;

                hls on;
                hls_path /usr/local/www/stream/tmp/hls0;
                hls_nested on;

                hls_variant _low BANDWIDTH=288000;      # _low          - Low bitrate, sub-SD resolution
                hls_variant _mid BANDWIDTH=448000;      # _mid          - Medium bitrate, SD resolution
                hls_variant _high BANDWIDTH=1152000;    # _high         - Higher-than-SD resolution
                hls_variant _higher BANDWIDTH=2048000;  # _higher       - High bitrate, HD 720p resolution
                hls_variant _src BANDWIDTH=4096000;     # _src          - Source bitrate, source resolution 
}
```

As you can see there is nothing special about that.
The generated log looks like this:

```
ffmpeg version 4.4 Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with FreeBSD clang version 10.0.1 (git@github.com:llvm/llvm-project.git llvmorg-10.0.1-0-gef32c611aa2)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local --mandir=/usr/local/man --datadir=/usr/local/share/ffmpeg --pkgconfigdir=/usr/local/libdata/pkgconfig --disable-static --enable-shared --enable-pic --enable-gpl --enable-avresample --cc=cc --cxx=c++ ->
  libavutil      56. 70.100 / 56. 70.100
  libavcodec     58.134.100 / 58.134.100
  libavformat    58. 76.100 / 58. 76.100
  libavdevice    58. 13.100 / 58. 13.100
  libavfilter     7.110.100 /  7.110.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  9.100 /  5.  9.100
  libswresample   3.  9.100 /  3.  9.100
  libpostproc    55.  9.100 / 55.  9.100
Splitting the commandline.
Reading option '-loglevel' ... matched as option 'loglevel' (set logging level) with argument 'debug'.
Reading option '-i' ... matched as input url with argument 'rtmp://localhost:1935/Test//'.
Reading option '-c:v' ... matched as option 'c' (codec name) with argument 'libx264'.
Reading option '-acodec' ... matched as option 'acodec' (force audio codec ('copy' to copy stream)) with argument 'aac'.
Reading option '-preset' ... matched as AVOption 'preset' with argument 'veryfast'.
Reading option '-b:v' ... matched as option 'b' (video bitrate (please use -b:v)) with argument '256k'.
Reading option '-tune' ... matched as AVOption 'tune' with argument 'zerolatency'.
Reading option '-vf' ... matched as option 'vf' (set video filters) with argument 'scale=480:trunc(ow/a/2)*2'.
Reading option '-f' ... matched as option 'f' (force format) with argument 'flv'.
Reading option 'rtmp://localhost:1935/Z006//_low' ... matched as output url.
Reading option '-c:v' ... matched as option 'c' (codec name) with argument 'libx264'.
Reading option '-acodec' ... matched as option 'acodec' (force audio codec ('copy' to copy stream)) with argument 'aac'.
Reading option '-preset' ... matched as AVOption 'preset' with argument 'veryfast'.
Reading option '-b:v' ... matched as option 'b' (video bitrate (please use -b:v)) with argument '768k'.
Reading option '-tune' ... matched as AVOption 'tune' with argument 'zerolatency'.
Reading option '-vf' ... matched as option 'vf' (set video filters) with argument 'scale=720:trunc(ow/a/2)*2'.
Reading option '-f' ... matched as option 'f' (force format) with argument 'flv'.
Reading option 'rtmp://localhost:1935/Z006//_mid' ... matched as output url.
Reading option '-c:v' ... matched as option 'c' (codec name) with argument 'libx264'.
Reading option '-acodec' ... matched as option 'acodec' (force audio codec ('copy' to copy stream)) with argument 'aac'.
Reading option '-preset' ... matched as AVOption 'preset' with argument 'veryfast'.
Reading option '-b:v' ... matched as option 'b' (video bitrate (please use -b:v)) with argument '1024k'.
Reading option '-tune' ... matched as AVOption 'tune' with argument 'zerolatency'.
Reading option '-vf' ... matched as option 'vf' (set video filters) with argument 'scale=960:trunc(ow/a/2)*2'.
Reading option '-f' ... matched as option 'f' (force format) with argument 'flv'.
Reading option 'rtmp://localhost:1935/Z006//_high' ... matched as output url.
Reading option '-c:v' ... matched as option 'c' (codec name) with argument 'libx264'.
Reading option '-acodec' ... matched as option 'acodec' (force audio codec ('copy' to copy stream)) with argument 'aac'.
Reading option '-preset' ... matched as AVOption 'preset' with argument 'veryfast'.
Reading option '-b:v' ... matched as option 'b' (video bitrate (please use -b:v)) with argument '1920k'.
Reading option '-tune' ... matched as AVOption 'tune' with argument 'zerolatency'.
Reading option '-vf' ... matched as option 'vf' (set video filters) with argument 'scale=1280:trunc(ow/a/2)*2'.
Reading option '-f' ... matched as option 'f' (force format) with argument 'flv'.
Reading option 'rtmp://localhost:1935/Z006//_higher' ... matched as output url.
Reading option '-c' ... matched as option 'c' (codec name) with argument 'copy'.
Reading option '-f' ... matched as option 'f' (force format) with argument 'flv'.
Reading option 'rtmp://localhost:1935///_src' ... matched as output url.
Finished splitting the commandline.
Parsing a group of options: global .
Applying option loglevel (set logging level) with argument debug.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Parsing a group of options: input url rtmp://localhost:1935/Test//.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Opening an input file: rtmp://localhost:1935/Test//.
[NULL @ 0x80609a000] Opening 'rtmp://localhost:1935/Test//' for reading
[rtmp @ 0x806089300] No default whitelist set
[tcp @ 0x806089380] No default whitelist set
[tcp @ 0x806089380] Original list of addresses:
[tcp @ 0x806089380] Address 127.0.0.1 port 1935
[tcp @ 0x806089380] Address ::1 port 1935
[tcp @ 0x806089380] Interleaved list of addresses:
[tcp @ 0x806089380] Address 127.0.0.1 port 1935
[tcp @ 0x806089380] Address ::1 port 1935
[tcp @ 0x806089380] Starting connection attempt to 127.0.0.1 port 1935
[tcp @ 0x806089380] Successfully connected to 127.0.0.1 port 1935
[rtmp @ 0x806089300] Handshaking...
[rtmp @ 0x806089300] Type answer 3
[rtmp @ 0x806089300] Server version 13.14.10.13
[rtmp @ 0x806089300] Proto = rtmp, path = /Test//, app = Test/, fname =
[rtmp @ 0x806089300] Window acknowledgement size = 5000000
[rtmp @ 0x806089300] Max sent, unacked = 5000000
[rtmp @ 0x806089300] New incoming chunk size = 4096
[rtmp @ 0x806089300] Creating stream...
[rtmp @ 0x806089300] Sending play command for ''
```

I think the error is clearly the Empty 'fname'.
But I don't know what to do about that?

EDIT:

Even if I change $name to my Streamname which I use in OBS the conversion isn't started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got it working.

After days of testing and rebuilding with debug support I found the issue.

All starts when you use the combination of:

- on_publish
- exec
- php-fpm

The on_publish request is handled first via php-fpm. It produces the following logs:

```
2021/11/29 09:50:42 [debug] 90542#0: epoll timer: 9996
2021/11/29 09:50:42 [debug] 90542#0: epoll: fd:15 ev:2005 d:00007FEFED509668
2021/11/29 09:50:42 [debug] 90542#0: *3 http upstream request: "/php/rtmp_auth.php?"
2021/11/29 09:50:42 [debug] 90542#0: *3 http upstream process header
2021/11/29 09:50:42 [debug] 90542#0: *3 malloc: 000056047409F050:4096
2021/11/29 09:50:42 [debug] 90542#0: *3 posix_memalign: 00005604740A0060:4096 @16
2021/11/29 09:50:42 [debug] 90542#0: *3 recv: eof:1, avail:-1
2021/11/29 09:50:42 [debug] 90542#0: *3 recv: fd:15 80 of 4096
2021/11/29 09:50:42 [debug] 90542#0: *3 http fastcgi record byte: 01
2021/11/29 09:50:42 [debug] 90542#0: *3 http fastcgi record byte: 06
2021/11/29 09:50:42 [debug] 90542#0: *3 http fastcgi record byte: 00
2021/11/29 09:50:42 [debug] 90542#0: *3 http fastcgi record byte: 01
2021/11/29 09:50:42 [debug] 90542#0: *3 http fastcgi record byte: 00
2021/11/29 09:50:42 [debug] 90542#0: *3 http fastcgi record byte: 36
2021/11/29 09:50:42 [debug] 90542#0: *3 http fastcgi record byte: 02
2021/11/29 09:50:42 [debug] 90542#0: *3 http fastcgi record byte: 00
2021/11/29 09:50:42 [debug] 90542#0: *3 http fastcgi record length: 54
2021/11/29 09:50:42 [debug] 90542#0: *3 http fastcgi parser: 0
2021/11/29 09:50:42 [debug] 90542#0: *3 http fastcgi header: "Location: /"
2021/11/29 09:50:42 [debug] 90542#0: *3 http fastcgi parser: 0
2021/11/29 09:50:42 [debug] 90542#0: *3 http fastcgi header: "Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8"
2021/11/29 09:50:42 [debug] 90542#0: *3 http fastcgi parser: 1
2021/11/29 09:50:42 [debug] 90542#0: *3 http fastcgi header done
2021/11/29 09:50:42 [debug] 90542#0: *3 HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Server: nginx/1.20.2
Date: Mon, 29 Nov 2021 08:50:42 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Connection: close
Location: /
```

As u can see, fastcgi sets the http code to 302 with Location "/".

This Location is the $name variable used for exec!

So we have to force this Location to be our streamname.

Example rtmp_auth.php

```
<?php
   $streamName = $_POST["name"];

   //Check for streamkey here

   //If okay, set Location and Return Code (Set 403 if Auth failed)
   header('Location: '.$streamName, TRUE, 200);
?>
```

After we Set the new Location manually the Log Changes to:

```
2021/11/29 09:57:56 [debug] 90618#0: epoll timer: 10000
2021/11/29 09:57:56 [debug] 90618#0: epoll: fd:15 ev:2005 d:00007F491020B668
2021/11/29 09:57:56 [debug] 90618#0: *3 http upstream request: "/php/rtmp_auth.php?"
2021/11/29 09:57:56 [debug] 90618#0: *3 http upstream process header
2021/11/29 09:57:56 [debug] 90618#0: *3 malloc: 000055F9E1EC9050:4096
2021/11/29 09:57:56 [debug] 90618#0: *3 posix_memalign: 000055F9E1ECA060:4096 @16
2021/11/29 09:57:56 [debug] 90618#0: *3 recv: eof:1, avail:-1
2021/11/29 09:57:56 [debug] 90618#0: *3 recv: fd:15 88 of 4096
2021/11/29 09:57:56 [debug] 90618#0: *3 http fastcgi record byte: 01
2021/11/29 09:57:56 [debug] 90618#0: *3 http fastcgi record byte: 06
2021/11/29 09:57:56 [debug] 90618#0: *3 http fastcgi record byte: 00
2021/11/29 09:57:56 [debug] 90618#0: *3 http fastcgi record byte: 01
2021/11/29 09:57:56 [debug] 90618#0: *3 http fastcgi record byte: 00
2021/11/29 09:57:56 [debug] 90618#0: *3 http fastcgi record byte: 40
2021/11/29 09:57:56 [debug] 90618#0: *3 http fastcgi record byte: 00
2021/11/29 09:57:56 [debug] 90618#0: *3 http fastcgi record byte: 00
2021/11/29 09:57:56 [debug] 90618#0: *3 http fastcgi record length: 64
2021/11/29 09:57:56 [debug] 90618#0: *3 http fastcgi parser: 0
2021/11/29 09:57:56 [debug] 90618#0: *3 http fastcgi header: "Location: Test_input"
2021/11/29 09:57:56 [debug] 90618#0: *3 http fastcgi parser: 0
2021/11/29 09:57:56 [debug] 90618#0: *3 http fastcgi header: "Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8"
2021/11/29 09:57:56 [debug] 90618#0: *3 http fastcgi parser: 1
2021/11/29 09:57:56 [debug] 90618#0: *3 http fastcgi header done
2021/11/29 09:57:56 [debug] 90618#0: *3 HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Server: nginx/1.20.2
Date: Mon, 29 Nov 2021 08:57:56 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Connection: close
Location: Test_input
```

Now the $name Variable is set for next use with exec Command.
I hope someone can save some Hours of testing with this Information.

Comment: So the empty fname is normal? `[rtmp @ 0x55a3ff9f5280] Proto = rtmp, path = /, app = live, fname =`. OBS Studio is working fine but I can't get it to work with `ffmpeg`.

Comment: I got it. I was mssing the ` -rtmp_playpath streamname/streamkey` part and ` -rtmp_app application` to rtmp://localhost/app.